# Display array of structs in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am writing a task application, and am trying to gather input from the user, and use that to display the updated UITableView with the user's created task.

## My problem is:

1. The user task list is not appending properly (every time a task is added the contents of the array are not being appended, but replaced.
2. The taskTable UITableView is not displaying the contents of the array of task structs properly.

The `TaskManager.swift` class takes in the task details and adds a task struct to the array.

```
import UIKit

struct task{
var name: String
var desc: String
var due_date: String

init(name: String, desc: String, due_date: String)
{
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc
    self.due_date = due_date
}
}

var TaskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()


class TaskManager: UIViewController {
var tasks = [task]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
 *   Purpose: Add new task to task array
 *   Parameters: task (struct) to add
 *   Return: n/a
 */
func addTask(name: String, desc: String, due_date: String) {
    print("got to add task method")
    tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc, due_date: due_date))

    print("value of tasks[0] is:",tasks[0])
    print("number of elements in array: ",tasks.count)
    //the task array count should increase as the user adds more tasks,
    //but from this code, it is replacing elements 
    //(only saying there is one element, the most recently added one)

}
```

Here is the `FirstViewController.swift` class, where the input is being read from the new task screen, and sent to the TaskManager class to add to the task list.

```
import UIKit

//display task class
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var taskTable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var taskName_txt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var taskDesc_txt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var taskDueDate_txt: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var taskDone_btn: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var addTask_btn: UIBarButtonItem!

var activeTextField = UITextField()


//Cancel task button function
@IBAction func cancelTask_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTasks_seg", sender: cancelTask_btn)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //taskTable.reloadData()
    //taskTable.reloadData()

}

@IBAction func addTaskPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addTask_seg", sender: taskDone_btn)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    self.activeTextField = textField
    activeTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 187.00, green: 128.00, blue: 74.00, alpha: 1.00)
}


/*
 *   Purpose: Triggered off user 'Done' button click
        Creates a task to add
 *   Parameters: button clicked
 *   Return: n/a
 */
@IBAction func doneTaskInput_btn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Done task input button pressed")

    //if user input is valid, create a task from data they input
    //return back to task table screen
    if(isInputValid() != false){

        let name = taskName_txt.text!
        print("Task name is: ",name)
        let desc = taskDesc_txt.text!
        print("Task desc is: ",desc)

        let due_date = handler(sender: taskDueDate_txt)
        print("Task due date is: ",due_date)
        print("Adding task to task list...")


        TaskManager().addTask(name: name, desc: desc, due_date: due_date)


    }//end check isValid

    //added task to array, now go back to task table to display tasks
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToTasks_seg", sender: taskDone_btn)


}//end function


/*
*   Purpose: checks if user entered a task name
*   Parameters: none
*   Return: true if user entered task name
        false otherwise
*/
func isInputValid()-> Bool{

    var taskName: String?

    if taskName != ""{
        taskName = taskName_txt.text
        return true
    }else{
        taskName_txt.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        taskName_txt.placeholder = "Add a task name"
        return false
    }

}//end isInputValid method

/*
 *   Purpose: Parses date from UIDatePicker to string
 *   Parameters: DatePicker to read date from
 *   Return: formatted string date
 */
func handler(sender: UIDatePicker)->String {

    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"

    let strDate = timeFormatter.string(from: taskDueDate_txt.date)

    return strDate
}//end handler method


/*
 *   Purpose: Remove cell
 *   Parameters: task table, edit value
 *   Return: n/a
 */
func tableView(taskTable: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){

        TaskMgr.tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        taskTable.reloadData()
    }
}

/*
 *   Purpose: Returns number of sections (columns) in table
 *   Parameters: table
 *   Return: number of sections (colums)
 */
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print( "setting number of sections");
    return 1
}



/*
 *   Purpose: Returns number of rows in array to the table view
 *   Parameters: taskTable, number of rows
 *   Return: number of rows (int)
 */
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TaskMgr.tasks.count // taskList.count
}

/*
 *   Purpose: Populate cells with data from array of task structs
 *   Parameters: task table, row to insert data
 *   Return: populated cell
 */
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:     UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default Tasks")
    cell.textLabel?.text = TaskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = TaskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

    return cell
}

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling everytime you segue to task manager view controller, its a new instance?

```
var tasks = [task]()
```

This could be resetting it too? 
I'd try putting the tasks array in FirstViewController then you can access the structs inside it directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no databinding in iOS unless you use something like Rx.  That means if you change the data you are responsible for tell the tableView to update itself with reloadData or [insertRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows).

There is a question of where you want to do this.  In the simple case you do it right after the add.  In the more sophisticated case you subscribe to notifications from TaskManager and taskmanager sends your view controller messages whenever the data changes (this keeps your data in synch acrosss multiple view controllers, which I am assuming is why you have a separate TaskManager).

Not that you are already doing this for delete.